# How do I change a canvas element’s speed with a custom html range slider and position the range slider under the header

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5-canvas

My first ever project is from a canvas tutorial that had vertical and horizontal balls bouncing around. I tinkered with it because I wanted it to only move left and right. I have since decided that I would like my second project to be a range slider that can change its speed. I found a fun-looking html range slider tutorial online and managed to finally get it on the canvas with z-index and have yet to get positioned in a fixed location under the header. My goal now is to figure out how to connect the range slider to the circle’s speed to go from a range of speed 5 up to speed 30 (line 12 of the JS code) as well as figure out how to position the range slider under the header as a flex-box so that when the browser size changes everything is still visible.  I am very new at this and hopefully, my goals and approach make sense.
Here is the code:

```js
var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;



var c = canvas.getContext('2d');

var x = Math.random() * innerWidth;
//var y = Math.random() * innerHeight;
var y = 300;
var dx = 10; //document.getElementById("ID NAME HERE"); This isn't                                  // Changes the speed of the object 
//var dy = (Math.random() - 0) * 8;
var radius = 30;

function animate() {
  window.requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  c.clearRect(0, 0, innerWidth, innerHeight);

  c.beginPath();
  c.strokeStyle = 'yellow';
  c.lineWidth = 10;
  c.fillStyle = 'darkblue';
  c.arc(x, y, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
  c.stroke();

  if (x + radius > innerWidth || x - radius < 0) {
    dx = -dx;
  }
  /*if (y + radius > innerHeight || y - radius < 0) {
      dy = -dy;
  }*/
  x += dx;
  // y += dy;
}
animate();

// Slider // 
// Slider // 
// Slider // 

const slideValue = document.querySelector("span");
const inputSlider = document.querySelector("input");
inputSlider.oninput = (() => {
  let value = inputSlider.value;
  slideValue.textContent = value;
  slideValue.style.left = (value / 1) + "%";
  slideValue.classList.add("show");
});
inputSlider.onblur = (() => {
  slideValue.classList.remove("show");
});

// Slider // 
// Slider // 
// Slider //
```

```css
#canvas-wrap {
  z-index: 1;
  align-items: center;
}

#overlay {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 60px;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

p,
label {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 10px;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

input {
  margin: .4rem;
}


/* Slider */


/* Slider */


/* Slider */

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:400,500,600,700&display=swap');
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

.range {
  position: absolute;
  /* Need to fix */
  top: 150px;
  /* Need to fix */
  left: 100px;
  /* Need to fix */
  z-index: 2222;
  height: 80px;
  width: 380px;
  background: #35f2ff;
  border-radius: 20px;
  padding: 0 65px 0 45px;
  box-shadow: 2px 4px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.sliderValue {
  position: relative;
  width: 110%;
}

.sliderValue span {
  position: absolute;
  height: 45px;
  width: 45px;
  transform: translateX(-70%) scale(0);
  font-weight: 500;
  top: -40px;
  line-height: 55px;
  z-index: 2;
  color: #fff;
  transform-origin: bottom;
  transition: transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.sliderValue span.show {
  transform: translateX(-70%) scale(1);
}

.sliderValue span:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: #664AFF;
  border: 3px solid #fff;
  z-index: -1;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(45deg);
  border-bottom-left-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  border-top-left-radius: 50%;
  border-top-right-radius: 50%;
}

.field {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.field .value {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #664AFF;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.field .value.left {
  left: -22px;
}

.field .value.right {
  right: -43px;
}

.range input {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 3px;
  background: #ddd;
  border-radius: 5px;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  z-index: 2222;
}

.range input::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #664AFF;
  border: 1px solid #664AFF;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.range input::-moz-range-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #664AFF;
  border: 1px solid #664AFF;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.range input::-moz-range-progress {
  background: #664AFF; //this progress background is only shown on Firefox
}


/* Slider */


/* Slider */


/* Slider */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<HTML LANG="EN">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>HTML</title>
  <link href="index.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

  <div id="canvas-wrap">
    <canvas></canvas>
    <h1 id="overlay">Circle moving left and right</h1>



    <!--<h2 id="overlay">circlemove</h2>  remove or put below h1-->
  </div>


  <!--Slider 
            move the slider left and right to control the speed of the circle
            !-->

  <div class="range">
    <div class="sliderValue">
      <span>50</span>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <div class="value left">
        0</div>
      <input type="range" id="speed" min="1" max="99" value="50" steps="1">
      <div class="value right">
        100</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- ^^^Slider^^^ !-->

  <style type="text/css">
    canvas {
      border: 1px solid black;
      position: fixed;
      background: rgb(39, 118, 163);
    }
    
    overlay {
      position: relative;
      top: 10px;
      center: -10px;
    }
    
    body {
      margin: 0;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <!-- <canvas></canvas> !-->
  <script src="circlemove.js"></script>



</body>

</HTML>
```

Comment: "hopefully the link works" -- it'd be better to put the code in the question itself as a [mcve]. You can make a [runnable snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do). Links disappear and break over time.

Comment: Good to know they break over time. I'll edit the post and try to figure out how to get the code to work. It didn't work each time I tried. The above result is after about an hour of trying to post the code. Thanks for the response.